# Reading and Writing to different S3 buckets with s3boto3storage and django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I've been working off a series of tutorials and have my django photo gallery uploading images to an AWS S3 bucket named "sitename-org" using S3Boto3Storage.  I have an AWS Lambda that creates a thumbnail from it and puts it in a different bucket named "sitename-org-resized".  I cannot figure out how to make a thumbnail member in Photo class that pulls the image (same filename) from the -resized bucket.  This was my latest attempt.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
   exclude = ('thumbnail',)

   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, upload_to='gallery_photos')
   date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   thumbnail = models.ImageField(storage=S3Boto3Storage(bucket_name='sitename-org-resized'), null=True, blank=True)
   uploader = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   album = models.ForeignKey(PhotoAlbum, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='photos')
   description = models.TextField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
#    
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)
      thumbnail = self.image
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake.  I was saving the object before assigning the thumbnail.  This works fine.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): #override save method to resize image
   self.thumbnail = self.image
   super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```